# How to apply a Hanning window without changing calibration scale of an image in Digital Micrograph?

Tags: image-processing, filtering, dm-script

I want to apply a Hanning window to an image before I process 'FFT'. I found a script written by Ruben Bjorge:

```
number size, sizeX, sizeY, top, left, bottom, right, ii, posX, posY  
image front, hannX, hannY, hann, avg, hannout

front := GetFrontImage();
GetSize(front, sizeX, sizeY);
GetSelection(front, top, left, bottom, right);      

// Create Hanning window.
ii = 1;
hannX := CreateFloatImage("", (right-left), (bottom-top));
hannX = 0;
hannX[0, 0, 1, (right-left)] = 1 - cos( 2 * Pi() * icol / (right-left));
while( ii < (bottom-top) )
{
hannX[ii, 0, 2*ii, (right-left)] = hannX[0, 0, ii, (right-left)];
ii = ii * 2;
}

ii = 1;
hannY := CreateFloatImage("", (right-left), (bottom-top));
hannY = 0;
hannY[0, 0, (bottom-top), 1] = 1 - cos( 2 * Pi() * irow / (bottom-top));
while( ii < (right-left) )
{
hannY[0, ii, (bottom-top), 2*ii] = hannY[0, 0, (bottom-top), ii];
ii = ii * 2;
}

hann = hannX * hannY;

// Subtract average from image.
avg = front - Average(front);

// Multiply with Hanning window.
hannout = avg[top, left, bottom, right] * hann;

// Do fast Fourier transform and display image.
fft = RealFFT(hannout);
```

By using this script, the calibration scale of the FFT is changed to 1. But it should be 0.11948, as all shown in the pictures below.

[image]
[image]

My question are: 
   Is there a way to apply hanning window without changing the calibration scale of image?

Or how to calculate the scale of the FFT image in terms of the scale of original image?

Since the rest part of my script needs the correct scale of the fft image, I'll appreciate that if anyone could answer this long question. Thanks.

Comment: For me it looks like in the first image (The FFT result) the calibration scale is undefined (this is because the units box is empty) so for unit less image each pixel in default is just 1. The calibration scale didn't change it is just undefined. Therefore define it yourself.

Comment: @ Amitay Nachmani: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to preserving calibration info in DM image expressions is to work with image references and in-place operations on clones of image objects as much as possible. Your example script becomes much simpler and more efficient when you transform it to use such techniques, as follows:

```
Image frontImage := GetFrontImage();

// Step 1 - extract and get info about the front image selection
Image frontSelection := frontImage[];
Number selW = ImageGetDimensionSize(frontSelection, 0);
Number selH = ImageGetDimensionSize(frontSelection, 1);

// Step 2 - subtract average value from selection and apply Hanning window
Image filteredSelection := ImageClone(frontSelection);
filteredSelection -= Average(frontSelection);
filteredSelection *= (1 - cos(2 * Pi() * icol / selW));
filteredSelection *= (1 - cos(2 * Pi() * irow / selH));
String selectionName = ImageGetName(frontImage) + " filtered selection";
ImageSetName(filteredSelection, selectionName);

// Step 3 - take FFT of filtered selection and display result
Image filteredFFT := RealFFT(filteredSelection);
ShowImage(filteredFFT);
```

The main differences here are in the two sections marked Step 1 and Step 2.

In Step 1, this script directly accesses the front image selection by using the selection operator, '[ ]'. This operator preserves the calibration (and tag) info of the original image.

In Step 2, the ImageClone function makes a complete copy of the selection's image object, including its calibration (and tag) data. The next three lines do the mathematical processing in place, directly on the cloned selection.  Note, in particular, that the Hanning window factors are applied very simply with a single image expression that is automatically applied to all the pixels of the result image.  There is no need for the while loops used in the example script.  In addition to adding code complexity, these are significantly slower than the implied looping done by the one-line image expressions.  In fact, the Hanning window can be applied in a single line that includes both the x- and y-dependent factors, as follows:

```
filteredSelection *= (1-cos(2*Pi() * icol/selW)) * (1-cos(2*Pi() * irow/selH));
```

Comment: It's genius to use 3 assignments " -=, *=, *= " to simplify the script! Using ImageClone is really a good solution for my question. Thanks for your comments on the example script and sharing yours!

Answer (score 1):

Your main question is about the propagation of calibration info when performing mathematical operations on DM image objects.  The short answer is that such info, as well as all the tag data attached to an image, is not transferred to the result image when one uses a simple assignment with an equal sign.  Each such image expression effectively allocates a new real image (with no calibration, tags, or name) and only its pixel values are transferred to the result image (which is also an uncalibrated, unnamed real image, by default).

There are several ways to make this script do what you want much more simply and efficiently (I will post a second answer to show this), but the minimal change to get the desired result is to replace the last line with the following three lines:

```
ImageCopyCalibrationFrom(hannout, front);
Image fft := RealFFT(hannout);
ShowImage(fft);
```

The first line transfers the calibration from the original front image to the filtered one from which you actually want a calibrated Fourier transform.  The second line uses the ':=' operator to have the image variable 'fft' point directly to the output of the RealFFT function, thereby preserving its calibration info.  In other words, this is an assignment by reference, not an image expression, and it bypasses the allocation of default (uncalibrated) real images for the intermediate and final result.  The third line actually shows the result (which seems to be missing from your sample code).

Comment: Thanks for bringing these details up. I had no idea about distinguishing assignment with/without reference. They make sense to me now. Thank you!